# Improper integral of $\frac{e^{i x^n/n}}{x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am unable to prove that the following integral gives
\begin{align}
f_n=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\frac{e^{i\frac{x^{n}}{n}}}{x}=\frac{1}{2n}\,, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}\,,
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{p.v.}$ stands for the Cauchy principal value.

**My two attempts.**

1. Consider the auxiliary integral in the complex plane
   \begin{align}
    I=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_C dz\frac{e^{i\frac{z^n}{n}}}{z}\,,\quad f(z)=\frac{e^{i\frac{z^n}{n}}}{2i\pi z}\,,
   \end{align}
   for $w\in\mathbb{C}$, and $C$ is a contour of integration. Closing the latter from above in an anticlockwise direction, the integral can be decomposed as

[image: Integration contour]

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 I=\oint_C dz\,f(z)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2i\pi}\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\frac{e^{i\frac{x^n}{n}}}{x}}_{f_n}+\int_\gamma dz\, f(z)+\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\Gamma dz\,f(z)\,.
\end{split}
\end{align}
Because the left-hand side integral on $C$ vanishes due to Cauchy-Goursat's theorem, we arrive at the following identity
\begin{align}
 f_n=-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\gamma dz\, f(z)-\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\Gamma dz\,f(z)\,.
\end{align}
Let
\begin{align}
 I_\gamma=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\gamma dz\,f(z)\,,\qquad J_\gamma=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\Gamma dz\,f(z)\,.
\end{align}
We conjecture that the integral on the semicircle $\Gamma$ will vanish due to the estimation lemma, so let us focus our attention on the contour integral on $\gamma$.

Consider the parametrization $z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, for $\theta\in\left[0,\pi\right]$. Then $I_\gamma$ is
\begin{align}
I_\gamma&=-\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\pi d\theta\frac{\left(i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)e^{i\frac{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^n}{n}}}{2i\pi \epsilon e^{i\theta}}\\
 &=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\pi d\theta\,e^{i\frac{\left(\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)^n}{n}}\\
 &=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\pi d\theta\, e^{i\frac{\epsilon^n}{n}\cos(n\theta)}e^{-\frac{\epsilon^n}{n}\sin(n\theta)}\,.
\end{align}
However, I do not know how to solve the latter integral.

2. The other option is the residue theorem. According to Wunsch,

[image]

Hence, recognizing $\alpha=\pi$, and the simple pole $z=0$, we readily obtain
\begin{align}
I_\gamma=\frac{1}{2}\,,
\end{align}
but this is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\cos$ part is even, hence integral on $\cos$ part vanishes. We only need to solve the $\sin$ part, when $n$ is odd integer.

$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_R \frac{\sin(\frac{x^n}{n})}{x}dx$$

Let $t=\frac{x^n}{n}$

$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\int_R \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{2n}$$

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how does the integral of your procedure gives $1/(2n)$?

Comment: Sorry, I double check the calculation and I missed a power index just now. The result is much more simple actually... @hyriusen